# how to stop thread by using boolean?

Tags: android, multithreading

i want the app the thread to stop in onclick and ondestroy, means i want the thread to stop when a button is clicked and when i quit app, now the thread wont stop even i quit it... where should i put my while(!shutdown)? Sorry im new to this.. Your help is much appreciated

```
    package com.example.suntracking;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //showing input and output
    TextView aziangle,elevation,numberof,rightasc,decli,hourangle,solartime,showinlat,showinlong,
    showintimezone,showindlst,showinofftime,showinoffazi,showinoffele,showinoffphi,showinofflamda,showinoffxi,
    showdate,showtime,showday;

    Button editting;
    Float latval,longval,offtimeval,offazival,offeleval,offphival,offlamdaval,offxival;
    int timeval,taketimesec,taketimeminute,taketimehour,takedateday,takedatemonth,takedateyear;
    String show1,show2,show3,show4,sshowday,takeampmtext;
    //for clock
    int timesec,timeminute,timehour,dateday,datemonth,dateyear,day,ampm;
    String daytext,ampmtext,showazi,showele,shownoday,showra,showdecli,showh_angle,shows_time;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Thread r;
    volatile boolean shutdown = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        loadSavedpreferences();
        r = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Write your code here to update the UI.
                               Save_fetchPref();
                               run_cal();

                            }

                            private void run_cal() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent j=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculation.class);
                                startActivity(j);
                            }

                            private void Save_fetchPref() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            timesec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                                            timeminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                            timehour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                            ampm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                                            if(ampm==0){
                                                ampmtext="AM";
                                            }else {
                                                ampmtext="PM";
                                            }
                                            dateday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                                            datemonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                            datemonth += 1;
                                            dateyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                                            switch(day){
                                            case 1:
                                                daytext="SUNDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                daytext="MONDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                daytext="TUESDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                daytext="WEDNESDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 5:
                                                daytext="THURSDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 6:
                                                daytext="FRIDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 7:
                                                daytext="SATURDAY";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            savePreferences();
                                            loadSavedpreferences();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
                }
        });
        r.start();
    }




    private void savePreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        Editor editor=savedata.edit();
        editor.putInt("timesec",timesec);
        editor.putInt("timeminute", timeminute);
        editor.putInt("timehour", timehour);
        editor.putInt("dateday", dateday);
        editor.putInt("datemonth", datemonth);
        editor.putInt("dateyear", dateyear);
        editor.putInt("ampm", ampm);
        editor.putString("daytext", daytext);
        editor.putString("ampmtext", ampmtext);
        editor.commit();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aziangle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAziAngle);
        elevation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvElevation);
        numberof=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNumberof);
        rightasc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRightAsc);
        decli=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDecli);
        hourangle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHourAngle);
        solartime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSolarTime);
        showday=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDay);
        showdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        showtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        showinlat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInLat);
        showinlong=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInLong);
        showintimezone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInTimeZone);
        showindlst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInDLST);
        showinofftime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffTime);
        showinoffazi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffAzimuth);
        showinoffele=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffElevation);
        showinoffphi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffphi);
        showinofflamda=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOfflamda);
        showinoffxi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffxi);
        editting=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bedit);
        editting.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


    private void loadSavedpreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        //input
        sshowday=savedata.getString("daytext",null);
        showday.setText(sshowday);

        takedateday=savedata.getInt("dateday",00);
        takedatemonth=savedata.getInt("datemonth", 00);
        takedateyear=savedata.getInt("dateyear", 00);
        showdate.setText(takedateday + "/" + takedatemonth + "/" + takedateyear);

        taketimesec=savedata.getInt("timesec", 00);
        taketimeminute=savedata.getInt("timeminute", 00);
        taketimehour=savedata.getInt("timehour", 00);
        takeampmtext=savedata.getString("ampmtext", "AM");
        showtime.setText(taketimehour + ":" + taketimeminute + ":" + taketimesec + takeampmtext);

        show1=savedata.getString("show1",null);
        latval=savedata.getFloat("latval", 0);
        showinlat.setText("Latitude : " + latval + ", " + show1);

        show2=savedata.getString("show2",null);
        longval=savedata.getFloat("longval",0);
        showinlong.setText("Longitude : " + longval + ", " + show2);

        show3=savedata.getString("show3",null);
        timeval=savedata.getInt("timezoneval",0);
        showintimezone.setText("Time Zone : " + timeval + show3);

        show4=savedata.getString("show4","No");
        showindlst.setText("Daylight Saving Time : "+ show4);

        offtimeval=savedata.getFloat("show5",0);
        showinofftime.setText("Offset Time : " + offtimeval);

        offazival=savedata.getFloat("show6",0);
        showinoffazi.setText("Offset Azimuth : "+ offazival);

        offeleval=savedata.getFloat("show7",0);
        showinoffele.setText("Offset Elevation : " + offeleval);

        offphival=savedata.getFloat("show8", 0);
        showinoffphi.setText("Offset Φ :" + offphival);

        offlamdaval=savedata.getFloat("show9", 0);
        showinofflamda.setText("Offset λ : "+offlamdaval);

        offxival=savedata.getFloat("show10", 0);
        showinoffxi.setText("Offset ξ : "+ offxival);
        //output
        showazi=savedata.getString("azimuth", null);
        aziangle.setText("Azimuth Angle : " + showazi);

        showele=savedata.getString("elevation", null);
        elevation.setText("Elevation Angle" + showele);

        shownoday=savedata.getString("jd", null);
        numberof.setText("Number of Days : " + shownoday);

        showra=savedata.getString("RA", null);
        rightasc.setText("Right Ascension : " + showra);

        showdecli=savedata.getString("declination", null);
        decli.setText("Declination Angle : " + showdecli);

        showh_angle=savedata.getString("h_angle", null);
        hourangle.setText("Hour Angle : " + showh_angle);

        shows_time=savedata.getString("s_time", null);
        solartime.setText("Solar Time : " + shows_time);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shutdown = true;
        Intent e=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Parameterlist.class);
        startActivity(e);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        shutdown = true ; 
    }


}
```

EDIT:

```
    package com.example.suntracking;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    //showing input and output
    TextView aziangle,elevation,numberof,rightasc,decli,hourangle,solartime,showinlat,showinlong,
    showintimezone,showindlst,showinofftime,showinoffazi,showinoffele,showinoffphi,showinofflamda,showinoffxi,
    showdate,showtime,showday;

    Button editting;
    Float latval,longval,offtimeval,offazival,offeleval,offphival,offlamdaval,offxival;
    int timeval,taketimesec,taketimeminute,taketimehour,takedateday,takedatemonth,takedateyear;
    String show1,show2,show3,show4,sshowday,takeampmtext;
    //for clock
    int timesec,timeminute,timehour,dateday,datemonth,dateyear,day,ampm;
    String daytext,ampmtext,showazi,showele,shownoday,showra,showdecli,showh_angle,shows_time;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Thread t;
    volatile boolean shutdown = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        loadSavedpreferences();
        t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (!shutdown) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Write your code here to update the UI.
                               Save_fetchPref();
                               run_cal();

                            }

                            private void run_cal() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Intent j=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculation.class);
                                startActivity(j);
                            }

                            private void Save_fetchPref() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            timesec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                                            timeminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                            timehour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                            ampm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                                            if(ampm==0){
                                                ampmtext="AM";
                                            }else {
                                                ampmtext="PM";
                                            }
                                            dateday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                                            datemonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                            datemonth += 1;
                                            dateyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                                            switch(day){
                                            case 1:
                                                daytext="SUNDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                daytext="MONDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                daytext="TUESDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                daytext="WEDNESDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 5:
                                                daytext="THURSDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 6:
                                                daytext="FRIDAY";
                                                break;
                                            case 7:
                                                daytext="SATURDAY";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            savePreferences();
                                            loadSavedpreferences();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }
        });
    }




    private void savePreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        Editor editor=savedata.edit();
        editor.putInt("timesec",timesec);
        editor.putInt("timeminute", timeminute);
        editor.putInt("timehour", timehour);
        editor.putInt("dateday", dateday);
        editor.putInt("datemonth", datemonth);
        editor.putInt("dateyear", dateyear);
        editor.putInt("ampm", ampm);
        editor.putString("daytext", daytext);
        editor.putString("ampmtext", ampmtext);
        editor.commit();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aziangle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAziAngle);
        elevation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvElevation);
        numberof=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNumberof);
        rightasc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRightAsc);
        decli=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDecli);
        hourangle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHourAngle);
        solartime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSolarTime);
        showday=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDay);
        showdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        showtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        showinlat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInLat);
        showinlong=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInLong);
        showintimezone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInTimeZone);
        showindlst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInDLST);
        showinofftime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffTime);
        showinoffazi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffAzimuth);
        showinoffele=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffElevation);
        showinoffphi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffphi);
        showinofflamda=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOfflamda);
        showinoffxi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowInOffxi);
        editting=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bedit);
        editting.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


    private void loadSavedpreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata= getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        //input
        sshowday=savedata.getString("daytext",null);
        showday.setText(sshowday);

        takedateday=savedata.getInt("dateday",00);
        takedatemonth=savedata.getInt("datemonth", 00);
        takedateyear=savedata.getInt("dateyear", 00);
        showdate.setText(takedateday + "/" + takedatemonth + "/" + takedateyear);

        taketimesec=savedata.getInt("timesec", 00);
        taketimeminute=savedata.getInt("timeminute", 00);
        taketimehour=savedata.getInt("timehour", 00);
        takeampmtext=savedata.getString("ampmtext", "AM");
        showtime.setText(taketimehour + ":" + taketimeminute + ":" + taketimesec + takeampmtext);

        show1=savedata.getString("show1",null);
        latval=savedata.getFloat("latval", 0);
        showinlat.setText("Latitude : " + latval + ", " + show1);

        show2=savedata.getString("show2",null);
        longval=savedata.getFloat("longval",0);
        showinlong.setText("Longitude : " + longval + ", " + show2);

        show3=savedata.getString("show3",null);
        timeval=savedata.getInt("timezoneval",0);
        showintimezone.setText("Time Zone : " + timeval + show3);

        show4=savedata.getString("show4","No");
        showindlst.setText("Daylight Saving Time : "+ show4);

        offtimeval=savedata.getFloat("show5",0);
        showinofftime.setText("Offset Time : " + offtimeval);

        offazival=savedata.getFloat("show6",0);
        showinoffazi.setText("Offset Azimuth : "+ offazival);

        offeleval=savedata.getFloat("show7",0);
        showinoffele.setText("Offset Elevation : " + offeleval);

        offphival=savedata.getFloat("show8", 0);
        showinoffphi.setText("Offset Φ :" + offphival);

        offlamdaval=savedata.getFloat("show9", 0);
        showinofflamda.setText("Offset λ : "+offlamdaval);

        offxival=savedata.getFloat("show10", 0);
        showinoffxi.setText("Offset ξ : "+ offxival);
        //output
        showazi=savedata.getString("azimuth", null);
        aziangle.setText("Azimuth Angle : " + showazi);

        showele=savedata.getString("elevation", null);
        elevation.setText("Elevation Angle" + showele);

        shownoday=savedata.getString("jd", null);
        numberof.setText("Number of Days : " + shownoday);

        showra=savedata.getString("RA", null);
        rightasc.setText("Right Ascension : " + showra);

        showdecli=savedata.getString("declination", null);
        decli.setText("Declination Angle : " + showdecli);

        showh_angle=savedata.getString("h_angle", null);
        hourangle.setText("Hour Angle : " + showh_angle);

        shows_time=savedata.getString("s_time", null);
        solartime.setText("Solar Time : " + shows_time);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shutdown = true;
        Intent e = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Parameterlist.class);
        startActivity(e);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        shutdown = true ; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written

```
 while (true) {
```

Instead of

```
while(!shutdown) {
```

You should also change

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    shutdown = true ; 
}
```

To

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    shutdown = true ;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: but as u see  if i use while(!shutdown) to replace while(true), the thread.start() is not affected, then the thread will still go on..

Comment: If you add while(!shutdown), the thread will only run as long as shutdown is false, so when you make shutdown true, the while will stop, and the thread will end shortly after. You can not stop a thread directly.

Comment: i changed it already. And i got that the content wont run since the beginning. I post the edited one.

Comment: No, and check my edit, and please try to explain what it is that still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, i changed it already but still not working. Suppose that Save_fetchPref() and run_cal() should run since the applcation start and i should get a result shown by them. One of it is the time should keep moving, but when i dont use thread.start() ,no result is shown even i changed it to while(!shutdown)

Comment: Ok i found the solution through net for this. They say that because my thread is using sleep so should use Thread.interrupt to make sure it will check again the status for shutdown. Besides, for my method Thread.start() is needed to run the thread. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

i'm also new to Android, but you can try to call this on your button onClick method:

```
  if(shutdown){

         mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable);
        thread.interrupt()
    }
```

Comment: still not working, btw i got error for the line thread.interrupt(), it suggest me to write thread.interrupted(),i guess its different thing